# Track GPS location - live feed

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am developing an android app for which i want to track user location.

Suppose, we have two users, `user1` and `user2`. 
`user1` is at fixed point and `user2` is moving. I want that, user1 can able to detect user2 position with GPS which is continuously moving.

Is there any API available for that?

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 4):

Something that may fulfill your requirements are Web Sockets.

In a largely simplified manner, they allow you to directly communicate with another client over the network, sending push notifications. Push notifications are great compared to the standard incremental checking, because they use less battery and new content can be delivered instantly.

There are a ton of Frameworks that work with both Android and iOS, incase you want to one day migrate your app to iOS through the same Framework.

The one I use is called PubNub, and there is tons of documentation for the Android API that can be found on the PubNub website.
They even created a demo application with similar features to what you requested.

They can be found [here](http://www.pubnub.com/in-action/). These examples do not provide code, but rather descriptions about how each PubNub feature was used to implement the system; however, [an example here](http://www.pubnub.com/developers/connected-car/) shows code of implementing such a process.

I believe you can simply set up a "chatroom" between the two cars, and send GPS coordinates back and forth. On the clients side, you would then parse these GPS coordinates (or lat/long) and present them with a Map API like the one you tagged (Google Maps).

Do keep in mind the prices for using PubNub. There are other alternative methods, like Socket.IO and Pusher, or non-realtime and much cheaper services like Parse.

With Parse, you would have to incrementally check the lat/long or GPS coordinates every X amount of time.

Let me know if you need more help!

Sorry I could not link more of the resources mentioned, I currently have a 2 link limit.

Comment: @Trend: Thanks for your suggestion. I guess sockets may so solve the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

No.

Would you like to own a device which has such an API?

You will need to create your own client that monitors your user's location (use the
[fused location provider](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) it's by far the best way to do it) and transmit user1 location changes
to user2 via a relay server.

If your time is short, and whose isn't, use some sort of [a BAAS platform](https://parse.com/) for your server.